# Linq Expression: Using Case Min Max from SQL in a Linq Expression

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

I'm trying to create a linq expression from an SQL query.

My big problem is to create this line:

```
CASE WHEN MIN() <> MAX() THEN 1 ELSE 0
```

in a Linq expression.

The SQL query is working fine:

```
SELECT 
    CLD.Id, CLD.Comments,
    CASE 
       WHEN MIN(AnswerComment.IdStatus) <> MAX(AnswerComment.IdStatus) 
       THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END AS statusDifference
FROM 
    CLD 
INNER JOIN 
    AnswerComment on CLD.Id = AnswerComment.IdCLD
INNER JOIN 
    ListDef on CLD.IdListDef = ListDef.Id
WHERE 
    ListDef.IdInspection = 1042
GROUP BY 
    CLD.Id, CLD.Comments
```

I'm trying to convert this SQL Query to a Linq Expression on C#.

```
var sql = (from CLD in db.CLD
                       join AnswerComment in db.AnswerComment
                           on CLD.Id equals AnswerComment.IdCLD
                       join ListDef in db.ListDef
                           on CLD.IdListDef equals ListDef.Id
                       where ListDef.IdInspection == idInspec
                       group CLD by new ComentRespostaLFDModels
                       {
                           IdComment = CLD.Id,
                           Comment = CLD.Comments
                       } into coments
                       select new ComentRespostaLFDModels
                       {
                           IdComment = coments.Key.IdComment,
                           Comment = coments.Key.Comment
                           * Here I need to do the case: "CASE WHEN MIN(AnswerComment.IdStatus) <> MAX(AnswerComment.IdStatus) THEN 1 ELSE 0" or in other place that I don't know
                       }).ToList();
```

Comment: possibly something like `statusDifference = coments.Min(c=>c.IdStatus) != coments.Max(c=>c.IdStatus)? 1 : 0`

Comment: and where do I should add this line?

Comment: in your commented line `* Here I need to do the case:`

Comment: oh yea! I tried.. but i don't know why I can't access the attributes inside the group by doing "coments.Max(c => c.IdStatus)"

Comment: you can change group clause like `group new {CLD, AnswerComment}` and then `statusDifference = coments.Min(c=>c.AnswerComment.IdStatus) != coments.Max(c=>c.AnswerComment.IdStatus)? 1 : 0`

Comment: Do you mind to create an answer to demonstrate it, please? I'm really newbie! haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change a group clause like

```
var sql = (from CLD in db.CLD
           join AnswerComment in db.AnswerComment on CLD.Id equals AnswerComment.IdCLD
           join ListDef in db.ListDef on CLD.IdListDef equals ListDef.Id
           where ListDef.IdInspection == idInspec
           group new { CLD, AnswerComment } by new ComentRespostaLFDModels
           {
               IdComment = CLD.Id,
               Comment = CLD.Comments
           } into coments
           select new ComentRespostaLFDModels
           {
               IdComment = coments.Key.IdComment,
               Comment = coments.Key.Comment,
               StatusDifference = comments.Min(c=>c.AnswerComment.IdStatus) != comments.Max(c=>c.AnswerComment.IdStatus) ? 1 : 0
           }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var sql = (from CLD in db.CLD
                   join AnswerComment in db.AnswerComment
                       on CLD.Id equals AnswerComment.IdCLD
                   join ListDef in db.ListDef
                       on CLD.IdListDef equals ListDef.Id
                   where ListDef.IdInspection == idInspec
                   group new {CLD = CLD, AnswerComment = AnswerComment } by new ComentRespostaLFDModels
                   {
                       IdComment = CLD.Id,
                       Comment = CLD.Comments
                   } into coments
                   select new ComentRespostaLFDModels
                   {
                       IdComment = coments.Key.IdComment,
                       Comment = coments.Key.Comment,
                       StatusDifference = coment.Min(c => c.AnswerComent.IdStatus) != coment.Max(c => c.AnswerComent.IdStatus) //if you want to return bool or coment.Min() != coment.Max() ? 1 : 0 if you want to return int
                   }).ToList();
```

Comment: really cool! but i need to do something like this.. but it's not working:    StatusDifference = coment.Min(AnswerComent.IdStatus) != coment.Max(AnswerComent.IdStatus)

Comment: you can always do coment.Select(c => c.AnswerComent.IdStatus).Min() != .Select(c => c.AnswerComent.IdStatus).Max()

Comment: really sad but i can't access the table from the join :-(.. it seems that the group by is blocking it

Comment: you can add this to the group by like                                                                                      "group new {CLD = CLD, AnswerComment  = AnswerComment } by new ComentRespostaLFDModels {}"

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
//Get all the ListDefIds where IdInspection == 1042
var listDefIds = db.ListDef.Where(x => x.IdInspection == 1042).Select(x => x.Id).ToList();

//filter CLD list by those ListDefId's
var filteredCLDList = db.CLD.Where(x => listDefIds.Contains(x.IdListDef)).ToList();

//filter answercomments by those whose IdCLD's are in the filtered CLD list
var filteredAnswerComments = db.AnswerComment.Where(x => filteredCLDList.Select(x => x.Id).Contains(x.IdCLD)).ToList();

//assuming status diff will always be same, calculate statusDiff
var statusDiff = filteredAnswerComments.Min(x.IdStatus) == filteredAnswerComments.Max(x.IdStatus) ? 0 : 1;

//filter CLD list again by filtered answercomments, then select new objects
var sql = filteredCLDList.Where(x => filteredAnswerComments.Select(x => x.IdCLD).Contains(x.Id))
            .Select(x => new { Id = x.Id, Comments = x.Comments, statusDifference = statusDiff}).GroupBy(x => x.Id).ThenBy(x => x.Comments);
```